# Is the following an Initial Value Problem or not?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, definition, initial-value-problems

I'm trying to solve an Initial Value Problem, but I'm not sure now if the problem I have in hand is even an Initial Value Problem. Notes from [Paul Dawkins' Course](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/de/eulersmethod.aspx) states IVP has the definition below - those are the initial values we have:
$$
\frac{dy}{dt} = f(t,y), \quad y(t_0) = y_0
$$

The problem I'm trying to solve on the other hand, is as follows:
$$
\frac{dy}{dt} = f(y), \quad y(t_0) = y_0
$$

In my problem $\frac{dy}{dt}$ is only a function of $y$, not $t,y$.

Does my problem qualify as an Initial Value Problem and can it be solved by Euler's method? The confusion arises, because I have an initial value and an initial direction. But the rate of change does not depend on time $t$ .

Thanks!

Comment: It's just a special case...

Comment: So it can be solved by Euler's method? Or is there a modification needed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To post a clear answer to your query, kindly note that
$$
y' = f(y), \ \ y(t_0) = y_0 \tag{1}
$$
is an Initial Value Problem (with an autonomous ODE and an initial condition at $t_0$) and this is a special case of
$$
y' = f(t, y), \ \ y(t_0) = y_0 \tag{2}
$$
(general case - when $f$ involves $t$ and $y$, the IVP (2) involves a non-autonomous ODE and an initial condition at $t_0$).

Euler's method or any finite-difference method used for finding estimates for the solution to the IVP (2) can be also applied for
finding estimates for the solution to the IVP (1).

Comment: Hi @Dr.Sundar, this is unrelated to your answer, hence I would be deleting this comment soonest. Please could you help out with this question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4435979/585488